# How do I remove duplicate rows with same column values in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to make a artisan command in Laravel to remove all venues that have the same address and leave the one with the lowest ID number (so first created).

For this I need to check 3 fields: 'street', 'house_number', 'house_number_addition'

This is how far I've got:

```
$venues = Venue::select('street', 'house_number', 'house_number_addition', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('street', 'house_number', 'house_number_addition')
    ->having('count', '>', 1)
    ->get();

foreach ($venues as $venue) {
    $this->comment("Removing venue: {$venue->street} {$venue->house_number} {$venue->house_number_addition}");
    $venue->delete();
}
```

Only the delete is not working but is also not giving an error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in Laravel, but if you don't want duplicates, you can set UNIQUE constraints in the database

Comment: Can you add the `dd($venues)` result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to delete an item, Eloquent needs to know it's id. If you make sure your models' id is queried, you can call `delete()` without issues.

In your query, however, that won't work because you have a `GROUP_BY` statement, so SQL doesn't allow you to select the `id` column ([see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)).

The easiest solution here is to utilize Eloquent's `Collection` class to map over the models, something like:

```
$uniqueAddresses = [];

Venue::all()
    ->filter(function(Venue $venue) use (&$uniqueAddresses) {
        $address = sprintf("%s.%s.%s",
            $venue->street,
            $venue->house_number,
            $venue->house_number_addition);

        if (in_array($address, $uniqueAddresses)) {
            // address is a duplicate
            return $venue;
        }

        $uniqueAddresses[] = $address;
    })->map(function(Venue $venue) {
        $venue->delete();
    });
```

Or, to make your delete query a little more efficient (depending on how big your dataset is):

```
$uniqueAddresses = [];
$duplicates = [];

Venue::all()
    ->map(function(Venue $venue) use (&$uniqueAddresses, &$duplicates) {
        $address = sprintf("%s.%s.%s",
            $venue->street,
            $venue->house_number,
            $venue->house_number_addition);

        if (in_array($address, $uniqueAddresses)) {
            // address is a duplicate
            $duplicates[] = $venue->id;
        } else {
            $uniqueAddresses[] = $address;
        }
    });

DB::table('venues')->whereIn('id', $duplicates)->delete();
```

> Note: the last one *will* permanently delete your models; it doesn't work with Eloquent's `SoftDeletes` functionality.

You could, of course, also write a raw query to do all this.

Comment: Cheers mate this was exactly what I was looking for!